# What's the general schema that Gmail uses with Bigtable

Tags: bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

Google now allows you to develop apps using BigTable (hosted as a product called "Cloud Bigtable" in Google Cloud Platform). However, I can't find too many example on how to design a schema for it. They have a document, but it's very high level: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design

My Question: what's the approximate schema for gmail (just the email list component). Is it a tall or wide design? What do they use for primary keys?

Any other production examples from big apps would be appreciated, but I think Gmail would be a great example.

Answer (score 7):

Schema design is very specific to your application. HBase fortunately has quite a bit of public material to help:

- There is a [Quora Thread](http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-examples-for-HBase-schemas-used-in-production) on production schemas.
- The [Time Series](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series) material that comes after the doc you mentioned is good.
- The [HBase documetnation](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/schema.html) has a chapter on Schema design.
- [Lars George](http://www.larsgeorge.com/)'s [HBase book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920014348.do) has some good discussion. He also talks on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HLoH_PgrLk)
- Ian Varley's [HBaseCon talk](http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/5-h-base-schemahbasecon2012) covers this as well.
- Amandeep Khurana has an [article](http://0b4af6cdc2f0c5998459-c0245c5c937c5dedcca3f1764ecc9b2f.r43.cf2.rackcdn.com/9353-login1210_khurana.pdf).